# Why does Julia interpolation not work in juliabox tutorial?

Tags: julia, interpolation

I'm using juliabox.com to learn Julia, but am having a very basic issue. I can't do the interpolation I'm being told to do:

[image]

`sum($foo)` just doesn't work as described, it just returns "syntax: "$" expression outside quote". This is at https://www.juliabox.com/notebook/notebooks/tutorials/introductory-tutorials/intro-to-julia/Exploring_benchmarking_and_performance.ipynb .

Is there a problem with the tutorial, or with me?

Edit: To be clear, my confusion here was not knowing '$' was paired with @benchmark in this context. The tutorial did not state this, so I saw no reason `sum($foo)` shouldn't work. Now I understand better. (Perhaps the tutorial's wording could be more clear.)

Comment: You are asked to compare these operations using `@benchmark` macro. See the example above with `sum(A)` vs `sum($A)`.

Comment: @bogumil: just post that plus a few lines of explanation as an answer, rather than comment?

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński You're saying the exercise is to benchmark an invalid expression? That worked when I tried it, but that's pretty strange to put in a tutorial.

Comment: @Lyndon: I first wanted to make sure what needs to be explained to Max. Given his additional question actually more needs to be added to the answer. I will write it.

Comment: Well - this got lengthy.

Comment: Also I think this question should not be down-voted. The `$` interpolation in BenchmarkTools.jl is not a simple topic (at least this is my opinion).

Comment: indeed! is not built in to the language (unlike interpolation into a quote or string), but is part of the `@benchmark` macro. I agree it is not obvious what is going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial you are using is aimed to teach you specifically how to correctly benchmark Julia code.

The key thing to understand what `$` is that it interpolates a value into the benchmark expression, so that it behaves as a variable whose type Julia knows at compile time (https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl/blob/master/doc/manual.md#interpolating-values-into-benchmark-expressions).

Why is this needed? A major performance problem in Julia programs is using global variables (https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables-1). In the following code:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x = rand(10);

julia> @benchmark sum(x)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  16 bytes
  allocs estimate:  1
  --------------
  minimum time:     18.492 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      21.306 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        30.284 ns (17.51% GC)
  maximum time:     38.387 μs (99.93% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     995
```

The variable `x` is global.

If you write `$x` instead of `x` then the variable `x` will be local (thus its type will be known for Julia at compile time). Note that this *interpolation trick* is only used for benchmarking - not for the real code:

```
julia> @benchmark sum($x)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     4.199 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      5.399 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        5.538 ns (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     48.301 ns (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1000
```

And the performance difference is exactly due to the fact that in the first time `x` is global, and in the second `x` is local.

In order to see that what is going on is allowing Julia to know at compile time the type of `x` consider the following code:

```
julia> const y = x;

julia> @benchmark sum(y)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     3.799 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      5.200 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        5.490 ns (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     30.900 ns (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1000

julia> @benchmark sum($y)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     4.199 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      5.699 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        5.615 ns (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     30.600 ns (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1000
```

In this case `y` is a global constant. Thus the compiler knows its type even though it is global, so in this case if you write `y` or `$y` does not matter.

Now you might ask why then `sum` does not have to be prefived by `$`. The answer is that `sum` is a function and thus its type is known at compile time.

Another way to think about `$` (I am simplifying a bit, but here as actually something different is done, you can investigate the details using the `@macroexpand` macro) is that it turns this:

```
julia> f() = for i in 1:10^6
          sum(x)
       end
```

into this

```
julia> g(x) = for i in 1:10^6
          sum(x)
       end
```

And now if you measure the time of both function with simple `@time` you get:

```
julia> @time f()
  0.032786 seconds (1.05 M allocations: 18.224 MiB)

julia> @time f()
  0.024807 seconds (1.00 M allocations: 15.259 MiB, 13.19% gc time)
```

vs

```
julia> @time g(x)
  0.017912 seconds (53.07 k allocations: 2.990 MiB, 17.93% gc time)

julia> @time g(x)
  0.001044 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
```

(you should look at the second timing as the first includes compilation time)

**In summary**

Prefixing global variable name with `$` is used for benchmarking purposes only. It makes sure that you get an information about the performance of the function in a type stable context (and this is usually what you are interested in).

**Additional cautionary note**

Benchmarking Julia code is sometimes tricky, as its compiler is very aggressive in optimizing the code.

For example compare:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> const z = 1
1

julia> @benchmark sin(cos(z))
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     1.999 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      2.201 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        2.394 ns (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     28.301 ns (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1000

julia> @benchmark sin(cos($z))
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  0 bytes
  allocs estimate:  0
  --------------
  minimum time:     25.477 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      33.030 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        35.307 ns (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     106.747 ns (0.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     993
```

You might wonder why using `$` in this case makes execution time slower. The reason is that as `z` is a constant then `sin(cos(z))` is fully evaluated during compilation (no computation takes place at run time), so what happens is something similar to:

```
julia> f() = sin(cos(z))
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_llvm f()

;  @ REPL[30]:1 within `f'
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define double @julia_f_16511() #0 {
top:
  ret double 0x3FE075ED0B926F7C
}
```

(and you see that if `f()` would be called it actually performs no computations).

On the other hand `sin(cos($z))` gets expanded in a way that makes Julia create a fresh local variable, call it `v`, then assign the value of `z` to it, and finally evaluate `sin(cos(v))` at run time (but knowing that the type of `v` is `Int`).

Note that this is faster than:

```
julia> x = 1
1

julia> @benchmark sin(cos(x))
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  32 bytes
  allocs estimate:  2
  --------------
  minimum time:     39.246 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      54.638 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        67.345 ns (8.80% GC)
  maximum time:     41.383 μs (99.82% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     981
```

as in this case the compiler does not know the type of `x`.